# The program in eclipse can not run in emulator after reinstall the system

Tags: android

I meet the problem:

```
[2013-05-14 09:53:23 - ShenXP] Android Launch!
[2013-05-14 09:53:23 - ShenXP] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2013-05-14 09:53:23 - ShenXP] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2013-05-14 09:53:23 - ShenXP] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'F:\bangong\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

I try to reinstall. And middle of the path configured to ensure no spaces. Adt is 21.1.0 and eclipse is 3.7. It is no problem to run in notebook. The SDK is a whole from low to high. I also do adb kill-server in command line and operate in adb start-server. What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go and check whether the adb is located at `F:\bangong\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe`, If it is there just run it as administrator. Then restart your eclips. Hope this will solve your problem.